# MIPS for-loop (Check if 0 using only beq or bne)

Tags: mips, qtspim

I am new to MIPS and trying to write a program that has variables that are either a zero or a one (These variables are either print or sum) and then four other variables that are just random numbers. If the variable sum or print is a one then perform an operation, if it is a zero do not. So if print was 1 and sum was 0 then just print out the four numbers and do not do the sum. How do I got about this? Do I have to create a different variable that is 0 and compare them to see if it is greater than 0?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one way to do it:

```
li $s1, 1 # this is sum
li $s2, 0 # this is print

SUM:
    slti $t1, $s1, 1
    beq $t1, 1, PRINT # branch to PRINT if we do not have to sum
    # sum here

PRINT:
    slti $t1, $s2, 1
    beq $t1, 1, EXIT # branch to EXIT if we do not have to print
    # print numbers here

EXIT:
```